# Magento One page Checkout issue not loading After shipping address

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Our Magento site is moved to new hosting server, since that while check out its not showing next content after "Shipping Address". Its calling following 2 requests via AJAX, and no response comes thereafter.

POST https://www.mysite.com/store/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/

200 OK  2.14s
prototype.js (line 1532)
POST https://www.mysite.com/store/checkout/onepage/getAdditional/

200 OK 965ms

Can anyone guide me what could be the issue. I have tried several things which found on SO and google but no luck.

Comment: Start inspecting from `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php:    public function getAdditionalAction()`

Comment: I have checked the code, the issue is, "saveBilling" in onepage.php returns error in this statement , $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();. I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Can you please add the error message to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got fixed after changing the shipping method. The issue was with Drop Shipping method.